# API Access to OSHA Establishment Search

Tags: labor

I have a use case where I need to be able to make an API request to retrieve inspection data for a given establishment. This is the page I can use to retrieve the data manually: https://www.osha.gov/pls/imis/establishment.html . I have not been able to find a relevant request in the API docs. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: any luck on finding how to access OSHA APIs?